# reactJS Material UI Font Icon set size

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

is there a way to make the font icon smaller in size?

I have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<FontIcon className='fa fa-quote-left' style={{ fontSize: '50px' }} />
```

Comment: You are missing an end quote.  Not sure if that's your problem or not.

Comment: @sma actually it's not the problem.

Comment: @dczii it depends how you use `FontIcon`. Did you try to add the `fa-x` classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use material icons font:

```
<FontIcon className="material-icons" style={{fontSize: '32px'}}>home</FontIcon>
```

Comment: Is there a way to set a global style so it is applied to all <FontIcon /> components?, if so mind sharing how?

Answer (score 1):

The [material-ui icon documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/) suggests using its property 'fontSize';

```
<FontIcon className="material-icons" fontSize="large">home</FontIcon>
```

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome, also import the font via stylesheet:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<FontIcon className="fa fa-star" style={{fontSize: '58px'}}></FontIcon>
```